# How to safely inject parameter into string DB query java?

Tags: java, database, google-bigquery, sql-injection

I have this bigQuery example code:

```
List<TableRow> rows =
                executeQuery(
                        "SELECT TOP(corpus, 10) as title, COUNT(*) as unique_words Where country = 'USA' " +
                                + "FROM [publicdata:samples.shakespeare]",
                        bigquery,
                        PROJECT_ID);
```

If i want to safely inject the country to that string

how can i do that?

I want to avoid the risk of sql injection and this is risky:

```
public void foo(String countryParam) {
    List<TableRow> rows =
                    executeQuery(
                            "SELECT TOP(corpus, 10) as title, COUNT(*) as unique_words Where country = '"+countryParam+"' " +
                                    + "FROM [publicdata:samples.shakespeare]",
                            bigquery,
                            PROJECT_ID);
}
```

*update*

couldn't find a clear example to Elliott Brossard suggestion:

```
public List<String> getVenuesForBrand(BrandChangeDataUi brandChangeDataUi) throws IOException {
    QueryParameter param = new QueryParameter();
    param.setName("country");
    param.setParameterValue(new QueryParameterValue().setValue("USA"));
    param.setParameterType(new QueryParameterType().setType("string"));

    List<QueryParameter> params =  new ArrayList<>();
    params.add(param);

    JobConfigurationQuery jobConfigurationQuery = new JobConfigurationQuery();
    jobConfigurationQuery.setQueryParameters(params);

    jobConfigurationQuery.setQuery( "SELECT TOP(corpus, 10) as title, COUNT(*) as unique_words Where country = 'USA' " +
                                    + "FROM [publicdata:samples.shakespeare]");



    List<TableRow> rows =
            executeQuery(
                    jobConfigurationQuery.toString(),
                    bigquery,
                    PROJECT_ID);

    printResults(rows);

    return null;
}
```

Comment: In your example, you will need to call `jobConfigurationQuery.setUseLegacySql(false);` to enable standard SQL. To test that the query parameter is available in the query, try doing `jobConfigurationQuery.setQuery("SELECT @country AS country;");`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at `queryParameters` under the [`jobs.query` reference](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/query). For the Java API, they are documented as part of [`JobConfigurationQuery`](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/bigquery/v2/java/latest/com/google/api/services/bigquery/model/JobConfigurationQuery.html). Note that query parameters are available only using [standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/).

Comment: I couldn't find a clear example. can you please have a look at my try and advise how to fix it?

Comment: SELECT ... Where country = @country FROM [publicdata:samples.shakespeare]

Comment: That won't work. For standard SQL, it would need to be `SELECT APPROX_TOP_COUNT(corpus, 10) AS title WHERE country = @country FROM publicdata.samples.shakespeare;`

Comment: you are right - forgot to fix table reference - my focus was on referencing parameter

Comment: but i want to use `bigQuery` syntax, so how can I use  `standard SQL` ?

Comment: Standard SQL is the preferred dialect for use with BigQuery, and all new features will prioritize standard SQL instead of legacy SQL, so I would recommend using it in your code. You can read about some of the differences between the two in the [migration guide](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/migrating-from-legacy-sql).

Comment: so i need to remove `[]` from the table name?
FROM `publicdata.samples.shakespeare`  and not `[publicdata:samples.shakespeare]`.

Comment: That's right. The migration guide (see the link in the previous comment) goes through some of the other differences too.